# Is there any way to use a JS variable as input instead of jquery selector "#id"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to know that, can we able to give a variable instead of `#anyId` inside a selector.

Actually i am trying this code,

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="aDiv123">
  <p id="abcd1234" class="abcd123">Click me!</p>
</div>

<script>
    $("p").live("click", function() {
        $(this).after("<p id='abcd123' class='abcd2323'>Another paragraph!</p>");
        var number = this.id.match(/^abcd(\d+)$/)[1];
        var iD = this.id;
        alert(number);
        alert(iD);
        var div = "#"+"aDiv"+number;
        alert(div)
        $(div).remove();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/sendmetamil/4748j/1/) for the above code.

Any suggestions about where i am doing it wrong!!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your Div has a different number from the paragraph, it should be:

```
<div id="aDiv1234">
<p id="abcd1234">
```

Not: aDiv123

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use a variable, assuming it contains a string that is a valid jquery selector, or a reference to a DOM element, or a reference to another jquery object.

The jquery api documentation is excellent if you're getting stuck with jquery usage.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: Yes, its working with the "p" element ID. Shall you explain me why i cant do it for the "<div id="aDiv123">" that contains the <p>???

Comment: #$!:*#... I am gone MAD. Thats is also working. bare me... :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe your problem is just a typo. You have elements with IDs `#aDiv123` and `#abcd1234`, but trying to remove `#aDiv1234`. Correct this and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

The $ JQuery function only takes a string for parameter, so you can build your own selector passing by some variables.

```
var sel = tag + ':visible';
$(sel) -> all visible "tags"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do an operation on the div which contains the paragraph, why not instead do:

```
$('p').live('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

... or ...

```
$('p').live('click', function() {
  $(this).parents('.discriminator').remove();
});
```