# Why does this RegExp match two strings?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var str = "abcd1234";
var first = str.match(/^abcd(\d+)$/)[0]; //matches abcd1234
var number = str.match(/^abcd(\d+)$/)[1]; //matches 1234 only
```

Why does this regex first match the whole of `str` and then match the numeric part? Looking at it I'd say it would always have to match `abcd` and then 1 or more digits? Isn't the 'abcd' a mandatory part of the match?

Incidentally I found this regex as part of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076570/is-there-any-way-to-use-a-js-variable-as-input-instead-of-jquery-selector-id).

Thanks.

Comment: the whole string is _matched_, the digit parts is _captured_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal in regex match results for  [0] to be the whole match.  and then [1]...etc. to contain the partial matches.  If you want both first and second part from the match, you will need to write something like:

```
  var m = str.match(/^(abcd)(\d+)$/);
  var wholematch = m[0];
  var first = m[1];
  var num = m[2];
```

Answer (score 6):

It's because 0 refers to the whole match while 1 refers to the first parenthezised group (which is actually 1234)

You could have this for example:

```
var str = "abcd1234";
var first = str.match(/^(abcd)(\d+)$/)[0]; //returns abcd1234
var chars = str.match(/^(abcd)(\d+)$/)[1]; //returns abcd only
var number = str.match(/^(abcd)(\d+)$/)[2]; //returns 1234 only
```

Comment: I think the terminology you are using is not very fortunate. The regexp does indeed match abcd followed by one or more digits, always. There is no such thing as whole regex and parenthesized regex as different regexps. `str.match` is a function which returns an array with the matches for the whole regexp on index 0 and the groupings (parenthesized parts) in subsequent indexes, index 1 is the first grouping and so on.

Comment: Do you think this new terminology is better ?

Comment: I'd edit the code comments. It should not read 'matches' it shoudl read 'returns'

Comment: Done ! (that was copied/paste from OP btw)

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

The capturing parentheses store the match from that part of the regex and hold it separate from the first result, which is the whole match.

Answer (score 0):

Any part of your regex in brackets '( )' becomes a grouping. This portion of the match is then also returned when you match your regex. This can be useful if you want to match a pattern and then use different parts of it for processing (eg a list of key value pairs in the format "key:value" you could make a group for key and for the value).

You can make a grouping **non capturing** by placing '**?:**' after the first bracket. The following will match your regex and not capture the grouping/brackets part:

```
var first = str.match(/^abcd(?:\d+)$/)[0]; //returns abcd1234 ONLY
```

Also gskinner has a nice [regex tester](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) that will show you the groupings for your regex (hover over blue highlighted text).